# How to export all jobs scheduled in Control-M

Tags: control-m

I tried save as option but its giving m an .emf file which is not readable.
Is there any way we can get all the jobs from Control-M in an Excel sheet?

job->same as-save

Answer (score 3):

You can save the data of jobs by clicking in **Monitoring** pannel, then **View** tab, select **Jobs** -> **List**. Then click in **File** button (**left corner**) and "**Save as**". This will exports an Excel file.

[image]